# How can I see what I voted for on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, statistics, personal-statistics

Is there a way to see what questions and answers I voted for? (Obviously I won't ask to see what other users voted for, but I'd like to see that info about myself)

Or: is there a way to find out what the question / answer ratio in my votes is?

Comment: Actually, access to that list would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Since google led me here, go to your stackoverflow profile, then on the far right of the various it says `votes` tab.

But there isn't on on ones profile at stackexchange.com though, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is not possible.  It's kept secret to prevent terrible things from happening; only the unicorns know this information

Comment: a) please define "terrible things" :-) b) then I should probably change the tag from "support" to "feature-request"?

Comment: @seanizer - a) the unicorns will get you b) It should be `feature-request` I think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I guess you can create a query on the Stackexchange data explorer: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new</strike>

Apparently you can't use the data dump, as votes are anonymized there. Disregard this answer (not deleting so the impossibility of this method is apparent; so somebody else doesn't post the same wrong idea tomorrow).

Comment: Vote data is anonymous.

Comment: This won't work as the UserId is only populated if it has been marked as a favourite. See explanation of Votes table here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678