# how to see my votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I list all my votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/can-i-list-all-my-votes)
>   [How can I see what I voted for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72463/how-can-i-see-what-i-voted-for)

I want to see all the questions and answers I voted for in the past (upvote/downvote), I cannot see any of such fields on my profile. If there exists a feature like that please tell me how to use that, if not please consider adding a feature like that.

Comment: There are also many other duplicates of this question including [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62052/how-can-i-see-what-i-voted-for-on-stackoverflow) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63135/see-what-you-have-voted-on) to name but a few.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but I searched well before posting.